# Error saying "contains number values but got a string"

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Attempting to put a constraint on my query via two Number columns:

```
query?.whereKey("entriesCount", lessThan: "entriesLimit")
```

But the query is returning the following error:

```
entriesCount contains number values but got a string (Code: 102, Version: 1.11.0)
```

It is clear in my data browser that these values are set to numeric values. So I am not sure why it is saying it is coming back as a String.

I do increment these values via CloudCode, but I don't see how that could cause this type confusion.

*Edited to share full query*

```
let query = Contest.queryWithIncludes()
query?.whereKey("timeSlot", equalTo: timeSlot)
query?.whereKey("gameKind", equalTo: gameKind)
query?.whereKey("contestKind", equalTo: contestKind)
query?.whereKey("creator", notEqualTo: User.currentUser()!)
query?.whereKey("entriesCount", lessThan: "entriesLimit")
query?.addAscendingOrder("createdAt")
```

Comment: Could you please show your full query? Also, if you receive an object, it may help if you take the object and mark it as an Int. (let newobject = object as! Int)

Comment: @penatheboss I added the full query to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line:

```
query?.whereKey("entriesCount", lessThan: "entriesLimit")
```

You're passing the string `"entriesLimit"`, instead of a number, which it expects. So pass it a number. Or if `entriesLimit` happens to be a variable of type Number, just pass it unquoted. So either:

```
query?.whereKey("entriesCount", lessThan: 5)
```

or

```
query?.whereKey("entriesCount", lessThan: entriesLimit)
```

Comment: Ah, yes: I thought I was comparing the "entriesCount" value of the object to the "entriesLimit" value. But indeed you can just compare on value to a number using whereKey: lessThan. I'll have to get creative then. Thanks